# Equivalent of readability score for speeches/public speaking?

Tags: speech, readability, psycholinguistics

I was wondering if there was any similar scoring to the common readability scores (Flesch-Kincaid, Gunning Fox index, etc.) which can establish approximately what level of reader would be required to understand a given passage on first read (by my understanding), but for a given text if it were read out. Certain grammatical constructs, such as many nested dependent clauses, will obviously be much harder to parse when spoken linearly, than with written text where we can (and do, unconsciously) jump back to previous points in the text to, for instance, check what the dependent clause is referring to.

Further, some stylistic pointers, such as 'never ending sentences with prepositions', may have little to no impact on readability, but when listening to text can be quite difficult to understand without lots of stress/verbal emphasis. This can lead to essentially 'getting lost' in the sentence, and as a result, completely missing the information - something that can't really happen in writing.

**Does there exist any website/program/algorithm for scoring speeches like this, considering these types of characteristics?**